# How to access a non-defined but typed property in a non instantiated class (DTO)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, dto

I am creating a logic to verify if all http body property are mandatorily part of my DTO. Using a custom decorator and a Interceptor in Nestjs, I could access req body in exec context metadata, but in time of validation, I should be able to verify if body properties are part of my DTO props - and those last ones I can't access though.

Despite this is actually a typescript doubt, I am telling you the context because if any of yours know another way to do what I am trying to, please feel free to let me know about that way too.

Below a code sample showing the DTO which properties I am trying to access:

```
export class CreateUserDTO {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;

  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @MinLength(6)
  @MaxLength(32)
  @IsAlphanumeric()
  password: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsDateString()
  birthAt: string | Date;
}

// trying to do something like this, but can't access any property in transpilation time, one time they're all undefined

console.log(CreateUserDTO.prototype.birthAt);
console.log(CreateUserDTO.birthAt);
```

Comment: To assert that all properties are expected, you can [use `ValidationPipe`s](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#using-the-built-in-validationpipe).

Comment: Thanks @OskarGrosser.  Actually I am already using class-validators Validation Pipes for each property individually, as you can see at DTO simple pipe decorators. But it doesnt works for validate if there is any property I was not expecting, in my body; out of these DTO declared properties. It actually returns a prisma error (500) when it try to find properties in database. I know I could just pass a destructed DTO object for each handler in controller, but for for bigger body forms it would be excessively verbose.

Comment: Try passing the [validation option `forbidUnknownValues: false`](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#passing-options). For security reasons, it is set to true by default.

Comment: Tryied to :_(   But for some reason remains not filtering the extra atrribute

Comment: Please **provide all relevant information** in your question then. As you mentioned, you are using `ValidationPipe`s, so how they are configured and other relevant parts of your project should be included in your question. Are you using the option `whitelist: true` or `forbidNonWhitelisted: true`? Those strip the object of or reject the request when the object has unknown properties, respectively.

Comment: Hi @OskarGrosser , thanks Ive tried to review these points you mentioned and realized I wasnt using the qhitelist feature; that one solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve it by setting the 'whitelist' option to true in class-validator configs. That feature strips validated (returned) object of any properties that do not use any validation decorators.

Refs.: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#using-the-built-in-validationpipe